# Unix and the python socket module?

Tags: sockets, unix

I've just come across sockets and the python socket module (and am quite new to python!). What are `AF_UNIX` and `SOCK_STREAM` variables (?) used for? I've found them in a bit of code (in a method of a class):

```
self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

What is this assignment doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AF_UNIX` is configuring the socket as a [unix socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).  A unix socket is a mechanism for two processes on the same system to communicate with each other. If it were set to `AF_INET` it would be a TCP/IP socket.

`SOCK_STREAM` is configuring how processes should talk over the socket, in this case the processes exchange a byte stream.  See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.progcomm/doc/progcomc/skt_types.htm).

You should also check out the [python socket docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html), as they're pretty good.